# How can i know the number of times that an eigenvalue is degenerate for a large matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues

As the title says I have a large sparse matrix, 262000 by 262000, and i want to know how the number of times that an eigenvalue is degenerate. I can get the eigenvalue using the arnoldi method but after that i am clueless in what should i do. I can't calculate all of the eigenvalues of the matrix since i run out of memory.

Comment: Use `Tally` on the resulting list of eigenvalues? Since they are numerical, you may want to `Round` them to an appropriate precision first, to ease the comparison.

Comment: The problem is: i can't calculate all of them without running out of memory.

Comment: That's an important part of your problem. Please edit your question to add that.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought that was obvious since i said that was a large matrix.

Comment: provide minimal real example. just reduce your matrix and insert ur question.
and what u tried with Large matrix that lead you to memory problem!

Comment: You might want to ask on a math site for a method to deal with such a problem. And if you have trouble with implementing it in Mathematica, come back here for help.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48470/calculate-the-algebraic-multiplicity-of-known-eigenvalues-of-a-large-sparse-mat

Comment: If there is a null-space solver for sparse matrices, then you can try to calculate the null-space of $A-\lambda I$ after you've found $\lambda$. Unfortunately, Mathematica's [`NullSpace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NullSpace.html) cannot do this and runs out of memory.

Comment: Adding to @Roman’s comment, you’d perhaps want to also check nullspace dimensions of higher powers in case the eigenvalue is defective.

Comment: Another (iffy) approach might be to perturb the matrix and see how many distinct eigenvalues lie close to the one of interest.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yea, i already did that and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

If your memory is big enough to compute the orthogonal projector to the complement of each eigenvector  and look for another eigenvalue of the same value in the projected matrix

```
   A . e = \lambda e
   P = TensorProduct[e, Transpose@Conjugate@e]
   (1-P) e = 0
   
   Solve[ (1-P).A.(1-P) . x   == lambda x,x]
```

Comment: I very much doubt that symbolic methods will be of any use for a matrix this size.

Comment: This is a minutes test over some numbers. Depends on how sparse the matrix is. I tested it for a digaonal  matrix and its unitary transformed with randoms of dimension 6. With these given,  dimensions it looks like a social media on pairs problem of mid town size.